# My function doesn't return anything

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, permutation

I have inserted an array of strings into Heap's function. Although the `function generate()` prints properly the output `console.log(permut);`, it doesn't return any data.

Version 1 with `return arr`

```
  var arrStr = ['a', 'a', 'b'];
  var generated = generate(arrStr, arrStr.length);
  console.log(g2);


  function generate(arr, n) {
    if (n === 1) {
      console.log(arr);
      return arr;
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        generate(arr, n - 1);
        if (n % 2 === 0) {
          swap(i, n-1, arr);
        } else {
          swap(0, n-1, arr);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function swap(a, b, ar) {
    var temp = ar[b];
    ar[b] = ar[a];
    ar[a] = temp;
  }
```

Version 2 with `permut = permut.concat(arr);`

```
  var arrStr = ['a', 'a', 'b'];
  var generated = [];
  generate(arrStr, arrStr.length, generated);
  console.log(generated);


  function generate(arr, n, permut) {
    if (n === 1) {
      permut = permut.concat(arr);
      //console.log(permut);
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        generate(arr, n - 1, permut);
        if (n % 2 === 0) {
          swap(i, n-1, arr);
        } else {
          swap(0, n-1, arr);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function swap(a, b, ar) {
    var temp = ar[b];
    ar[b] = ar[a];
    ar[a] = temp;
  }
```

Version 1 returns undefined for variable `generated` and version 2 returns an empty array.

I've tried to return a test string 'asd' but still don't get anything.

Comment: You call the function recursively, but what do you do with the result of the recursive call? Where in the `else` path do you actually return anything?

Comment: The function works properly. In the `else` path the `n` is reduced until it's `n===1` where the problematic return is executed.

Comment: In the code  you show, if `n !== 1` (i.e. in the `else` part) you don't have a `return` statement. I.e. the function doesn't return anything. If you want to return a value, you actually have to use the `return` statement. `if ... else` is binary, in that it *either* does something (if the condition is true) or it does *something else*. In your function, the *something else* part is executed by the first initial call, and it doesn't return anything. I suggest you step through the code in a debugger.

Comment: Thanks, I just started to use Mozilla's debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared within a JavaScript function, become LOCAL to the function. Have a look at Javascript **scopes**. In another words, changes you'll made to the function parameter inside the function won't impact the parameter variable outside the function.

Just return the generated object at the end of your algorithm.

Example:

```
var n = 1;
incrementByOne(n);
console.log(n) //still 1

function incrementByOne(number) {
    number++;
}
```

Solution is to return the result and get it with a variable:

```
var n = 1;
n = incrementByOne(n);
console.log(n) //now it's 2

function incrementByOne(number) {
    return number++;
}
```

Comment: I think that's what I've done in `var generated = generate(arrStr, arrStr.length);`

Comment: What are you trying to do with the algorithm ?